# angularJS how to reset form in modal directive

Tags: angularjs, forms, modal-dialog, reset

I want to use AngularJS form directive on my own directives for modal dialog. Plunker here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Gw5XeKMxNDYafXgcAkRk

works on index.html

```
$scope.toggleModal2 = function() {
  console.log( $scope.newForm2 );
  $scope.newForm2.$setPristine();
  $scope.newForm2.$setValidity();
  $scope.newForm2.$setUntouched();
}
```

Not working on modal dialog.

On index.html page, if I tried to changed 'Other Name' and left it with empty input, then red error 'required' will show up. Then I click away, and click rest, it'll clear the form validity and setPristine, and 'required' will disappear.

Then I have another form on the pop up Modal dialog. When I close it by 'cancel', browser debugger says 'TypeError: undefined is not a function'. the same $scope.newForm1 is 'undefined', won't get me the form as the above case.

I know now the modal directive has an isolated scope here. Is there a way to work around this?

I tried with bootstrap modal too, and it's the same.

Thanks.